# Canvas and mouse position dont align

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, offset

So I have this little project and code,

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Urrby/bhdx6o3L/
```

The problem is I can't get the line to match the tip of the mouse, there is always space between the cursor and the line drawn. I know this has been asked 100 times, but I don't understand how to resize the canvas and window and mouse position to match. I'm not looking for just a solution, It would be nice if someone can dumb it down and explain why this doesn't work, and what is it that I have to fix. I'm really lost.

Here is the JS code

```
let coord = { x: 0, y: 0 };

function resize() {
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
  


  function start(event) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
    reposition(event);
  }

  function reposition(event) {
    coord.x = (event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft);
    coord.y = (event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
  }

  function stop() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  }

  function draw(event) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
    reposition(event);
    ctx.lineTo(coord.x, coord.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that in your CSS you set the width and height of the canvas (in a couple of places, in one the width is set to 900px, and right at the end you set it to 100vw).

Take these out so that the JS setting of the width and height properties can do their job.

If you do this you will find that your cursor and line are together. If you remove your cursor 'hand' you should see the ordinary point of the cursor right on the line that is being drawn.

Because you've used a sort of icon as cursor you'll have to move that relative to the normal cursor position as at the moment it looks as though it's the top of the pencil rather than the tip that is doing the drawing.

Comment: That solves the problem of Offset, but what can I do If I want to keep my canvas 900x600?
If I remove the canvas width, the canvas is to large. I would like it to. fit on the page, without scrolling

Comment: It’s up to you how you set the canvas width. In the snippet here it is set to the inner width and height of the viewport. If you want it to be a fixed width then use the fixed dimensions in the JS instead of the innerWidth/height, but be aware of not then being responsive.